# How to get the data labels below the xAxis in a column graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/agq6ebjd/1/`
```

In the above link, how can I get the data labels A, B, C with are inside the bars, out of the bars and below the x-Axis?[Expected Result to have the label below the bars shown like screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mdaM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable data labels and use x-axis labels instead. Just add `name` property to the data points and set `xAxis.type` as 'category'.

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            ...
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        ...
    }
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/drgkt598/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type

Comment: could you please help me with this when the yAxis max value is set dynamically by highchart. how to fetch that value to see what the highchart has set i tried to console chart.yAxis[0].max and chartSettings.yAxis[0].getExtremes all these are returning undefined is there a way to fetch the yAxis Max of the chart ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Nagachandra, Both of the ways should work. Could you provide me with an example of use?